# UITableView dequeued cells reloading old images

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I know this has been asked many many times but please bear with me as I've tried for a could days to find a solution.

I have an rss parser, a tableview with: text, detail, and images set to the AccessoryDisclosureIndicator.view.

The images load great with simple GCD async: fast scrolling for hundreds of result. NO lag, NO errors if I have a good connection.

The problem is, for a split second - they flicker on load, because the cell is being reused. Also if the connection is poor it will sometimes leave the straggling image BUT the text/detail are correct, only the image is old... So let me repeat, the text/detail updates fine and NEVER gets re-queued wrong, just the image sometimes rarely gets queued wrong on bad connections/seizure-scrolling back and forth fast.

My question, can someone help me cache/tag the cell.accs.views? I tried setting cellIDs but had trouble with my implementation. My below code works great if the connection never slows, just a slight flicker on re-queuing a cell which i don't mind.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    [cell.textLabel setNumberOfLines:3];
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14.0];

    [cell.detailTextLabel setNumberOfLines:3];
    cell.detailTextLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0];
    cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
}

RSSItem * rssItem = (RSSItem *)(_rssParser.rssItems)[indexPath.row];

dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH,  0ul);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    //This is what you will load lazily
    NSData   *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:rssItem.imageURL]];
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        UIImageView *accImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithData:data ]];

        [accImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, accImageView.image.size.width, 92)];
        cell.accessoryView = accImageView;

        //[cell setNeedsLayout];//not needed
    });
});

[cell.textLabel setText:rssItem.title];
[cell.detailTextLabel setText:rssItem.summary];

return cell;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I did using SDWebImage, I was forced to use a placeholder for all cells, I just set the ones without images to a small chevron icon. Works as expected. Thanks everybody.

```
RSSItem * rssItem = (RSSItem *)(_rssParser.rssItems)[indexPath.row];

if (rssItem.imageURL == nil ){
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20)];
    [imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:rssItem.imageURL] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"chevron.png"]];
    cell.accessoryView = imageView;
}else{
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 110, 96)];
    imageView.contentMode  = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    [imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:rssItem.imageURL] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"loading.png"]];
    cell.accessoryView = imageView;
}

[cell.textLabel setText:rssItem.title];
[cell.detailTextLabel setText:rssItem.summary];

return cell;
```

Answer (score 10):

The key issue is that before you `dispatch_async` to get the new image (which you know may take a few moments, even seconds on a slow connection), reset the old one or load it with a placeholder image.

Two secondary issues:

1. Be aware that it's possible, if using a very slow network, that by the time the image gets back, that you could have scrolled the cell off the screen (e.g. imagine that you flicked the scroll view up and then, while images were still being loaded, you flicked it back down). You really should make sure that the cell is still visible before trying to set the image.

   You can do this by checking (on the main queue) whether the cell is even visible:

   ```
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
       UITableViewCell *updateCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
       if (updateCell != nil) {
           // update image in `updateCell`
       }
   });
   ```

   Please note, this `UITableView` method, [`cellForRowAtIndexPath`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/cellForRowAtIndexPath:), should not be confused with the `UITableViewDataSource` method, [`tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDataSource/tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:). The former simply checks to see if the cell is visible, and if so, returns a pointer to it. The latter, obviously, is the method that you reference in your question, for creating and configuring table view cells.

   Also note that this idea, that you use the `NSIndexPath` to check to see if the cell is still visible, assumes that no additional rows could have possibly been inserted in the table view in the intervening time. This often is not a valid assumption, so you may even have to go back to the underlying model and re-calculate the `indexPath` for this cell before proceeding with the above logic to see if that cell is still visible or not.
2. You might not want to use a global queue because on really slow network your requests might start to get backlogged and you might end up with a lot of concurrent network requests. This is a problem because (a) the system can't do more than 4 or 5 concurrent requests at a time, anyway; and (b) you'll be using up the limited number of worker threads provided by iOS. You really shouldn't have more than 4 or 5 concurrent requests (if you have more than that, not only will you see no performance gain, but they'll actually block and eventually timeout). I'd suggest you consider using a `NSOperationQueue` for which you set `maxConcurrentOperationCount` to four or five.

   Also, this affords one final optimization, notably making these `NSOperation` subclass requests cancelable (and, obviously, making the cancelation logic actually cancel the network request contained therein). Thus, if you scroll quickly to the 100th row in the table, you really don't want to have the visible cells waiting for the image downloads for the previous 99 rows to finish first. If you cancel the image request for cells that scrolled off screen, that resolves this problem.

If you want to diagnose your app's behavior on a really slow network connection, I'd suggest that you get the Network Conditioner, which can have your Mac simulate anything ranging from full speed to a really poor quality Edge network on the simulator. In Xcode menu in Xcode, choose "Open Developer Tool..." and then pick "More Developer Tools". After you log in, you'll see an option for "Hardware IO Tools for Xcode". The Network Conditioner tool is there. You can test your app in worst case scenarios, which may get you thinking about not only the two problems I outline above, but also more advanced features like caching of images and the like.

You really want to cache images, at the very least to persistent storage, ideally to both RAM and persistent storage. There are `UIImageView` categories that tackle both the asynchronous issues above, as well as offer some caching: Two that you might consider are [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) and [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking).

Comment: Ohhh gawd, with the line conditioner ON I see that the cell will cycle through 4 or 5 images until it gets the correct one... Why is this so hard? I'm all for caching, but im having trouble adding the tags and checking against them or I just cant find a good tutorial...

Comment: @JoshP Either [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) or [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)'s `UIImageView` category both would make your life *much* easier. If you really want to write your own, let me know and I can help you find good answers. When I wrote my own, I personally use a combination of `NSCache` for RAM cache and `Documents` folder for persistent storage cache (though I think the convention is now to use a separate `Cache` folder). I'd really suggest you stick with AFNetworking or SDWebImage.

Comment: I will try those, people do this everyday and I cant seem to find a good tutorial, it just boggles the mind that the table forgets that its scrolling, really? How can it remember the text but forget the image? This seems like something that apple should solve automagically :) I'm about to not dequeue the cells but that is ridiculous. Thanks, in my mind i know it can be done by modifying my code above with no external classes and maybe just a appdel cache, but yea like I said i need to look harder for better examples.

Comment: I dont want a placeholder, beacause i dont like how they look, and also because I cant setup the placeholder frame before hand because I dont know the size of the image, I dont want an center auto-filled 40x40 icon, I want an image who's only limit is height. All the cell subclasses ive seen fail to create dynamic sizes. So... yea, how would someone pass the downloaded images frame width before downloading the image?

Comment: Not enough rep to chat, 1) I see that SDWebImage crashes on [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:rssItem.imageURL] 2) I want to retain aspect ratio of the original image, i limit height to 96 and set width of the frame to width of the image

Comment: Linker error I was importing the SD files, not the framework (rtfm), it actually seems ok now but i only tested for 30sec, thanks a bunch Rob. Main problem, not every cell has an image, not every cell is the same aspect ratio. Which is why I want to set the placeholder to image.width, if image == nil == [no width], if image == image then frame == image width

Comment: @JoshP Understood. Most people solve the different aspect ratio problem in a `UITableViewCell` by setting the `UIImageView` to be fixed size but use a `contentMode` of either `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit` or `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit`, because it can be annoying for the user if they're reading something on the screen and it moves because some asynchronous update of an image caused the screen to be redrawn. But if you figure out a graceful UX to deal with this, that's brilliant.

Comment: Yea, not every cell has an image, so I dont want to preset a placeholder. The more I look at it matts answer might be the way to go, because if it loads in WillAppear first and the image returns nil the table wont set it... hopefully...

Comment: @JoshP First, if you want to accept a different answer, please do. We all just want you to get an answer that works for you. Second, if I understand you, you're contemplating giving up on asynchronous image loading. Sometimes we have to do that, but be aware, that performance will be adversely affected. Make sure to test on a slow network (or you can simulate this with the "network conditioner"). What looks fine on your standard simulator may be unbearable on a slow Edge network. If you go synchronous, make sure to use a spinner or other UI clues so the user understands what's going on.

Comment: I like your answer im just frustrated... Doesnt someone have a class with layout on the right side that checks against nil images and aspect ratio? Seems like a simple thing, could I just not dequeue the cells? I have less than 200max...

Comment: Well a combination of: a custom cell class accessory.view w/ autosize, and SDWebImage, and a custom uiimageview class with autosize, appear to be the way to go. :) thanks again Rob.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to clear out the old image when reusing the cell.

At the end, you can just add:

```
cell.accessoryView = nil;
```

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is, for a split second - they flicker on load, because the cell is being reused

But that's your answer right there. The cell is being reused, and I don't see anything in your code that removes the image. If the image is not the right image for this row (because it is being reused in a different row), you need to set `cell.accessoryView` to nil (or to an image view with a placeholder image) *now*. The right image won't come along until *later* (`dispatch_async`).

However, the code you are using is highly flawed, because it is fetching the image from the Internet *every time*, even if we've already seen this row and therefore already downloaded the image. My book has much better code for loading the images in a table view by downloading them if necessary and storing them thereafter. It also shows you how to stop the download if the row is scrolled off the table before the image arrives, thereby saving bandwidth:

http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch37.html#_http_requests

Scroll down to where it says "Suppose, for example, you need to download images to serve as thumbnails in the cells of a UITableView. Let’s consider how these images can be supplied lazily on demand."

Comment: Yea... I figured I need to delagate a cache to prevent redownloading, but yes... i also need to figure out how to tag the cells... I'm gunna read your smaples, but yea im a noob

Comment: Actual downloadable working example project here: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/tree/master/ch37p920downloader/p754p772downloader

Comment: Your example looks like something id like to try, thanks. Wanna give me a hint at how to run my rss.items.title/text/imgurl/ array through addobject:d?

Comment: Would this work?  self.model = [NSMutableArray array]; for (_rssitems.items count) {NSURLRequest* req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:rssitems.items.imgurl]